# iOS web app black-translucent leaves a white bar on the bottom?

Tags: ios, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

When setting the iOS status bar style to translucent the content of my page moves up and leaves a white border in the bottom of the web app. `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`

If I use `default` instead of `black-translucent` it will not show a white bar in the bottom, but the content will not show behind the statusbar.

How do I fix this to fill the content on the whole display?

[image]

Comment: i have the same problem. did you happen to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a solution yet? I have the same problem